# How to register different kinds of users in Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, roles

I am a teacher and I want to write my own system for our school to manage all the stuff.

For this I need to register first my school (in the future there will perhaps other schools which want to use our system).
Then I want to be able to register new **teachers, pupils, parents** and other workers like the **household personal** and so on...

My question now is: is it enough for this usage to get the users different **roles** or should I create different **user classes** for every different kind of user? For example Appbundle/Entity/User/teachers.php

Perhaps there are other solutions like ACL or voters which I don't really know much about.

Comment: Use one User Entity with different roles like ROLE_TEACHER, ROLE_PARENTS, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

- a User entity with basic data and authentication credentials
- an Activity entity that link a User to a School with a `type` enum field (e.g. "teacher", "parent", "pupil", ...)
- a custom voter based on the Activity of the logged in User in the School he/she try to access to.

I think it's future proof: a teacher in a school may be a parent in an other one :)

Answer (score 0):

personally I would use a single user entity that can assume multiple role, unless the different roles will have wildly varying attributes.

A good example can be found on this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html